# Problems Creating Login/Registration Page with servlets/MySQL in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, registration

So here is my issue. I am working on a school project and I am basically hitting a wall. I cannot get my RegistrationServer to work at all. I can get it to run, and correctly display the Registration.jsp that it is built behind, but none of the information is entered into the database at all. In fact, I cannot even tell if that is where exactly I am failing. Here is the code for the Registration function:

Registration.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style>
div.container {
    //width: 100%;
   // border: 1px solid gray;
  //  padding:5px;

}

table, th, td {
   //border: 1px solid black;
}
.textright{float:right;padding:10px}

</style>

<title>Registration</title>
<script> 
function validate()
{ 
var firstname = document.form.firstname.value;
var lastname = document.form.lastname.value;
var username = document.form.username.value; 
var password = document.form.password.value;
var address = document.form.address.value;
var contact = document.form.contact.value;
if (firstname==null || firstname=="")
{ 
alert("First Name can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
else if (lastname==null || lastname=="")
{ 
alert("Last Name can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
else if (username==null || username=="")
{ 
alert("Username can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
else if (password==null || password=="")
{ 
alert("Password can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
else if(password.length<6)
{ 
alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long."); 
return false; 
}
else if (address==null || address=="")
{ 
alert("Address can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
else if (contact==null || contact=="")
{ 
alert("Contact can't be blank"); 
return false; 
}
} 
</script> 
</head>


<body bgcolor="#D3D3D3">
<form name="form" action="RegistrationServlet" method="post" 
onsubmit="return 
validate()">
<td style="float:left"><image 
src="file:///G:/College/Winter%202018/CSC%20363/Computer%20logo.png" 
width="100px" height="100px"></image></td>
<p style="float:right"><b> ${members[3]} <br> CSC 363<br>Final Project</b> 
</p>

        <td style="clear:float"></td>
        <p style="align-text"left">Team</p>
        <p style="float:left">${members[0]} <br> ${members[1]} <br> 
        ${members[2]} </p>
        <td style="close:float"></td>

<table style="float:right">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact</td>
<td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><%=(request.getAttribute("errMessage") == null) ? ""
: request.getAttribute("errMessage")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

RegistrationServlet

```
package com.mvc.RegistrationServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mvc.Bean.RegistrationBean;
import com.mvc.Dao.RegistrationDao;
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public RegistrationServlet() {
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String[] members = new String[4];
 members[0] = "Jamie W.";
 members[1] = "Evan D.";
 members[2] = "Tim D.";
 members[3] = "Hardware Plus";

request.setAttribute("members", members);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Registration.jsp").forward(request, 
response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String address = request.getParameter("address");
String contact = request.getParameter("contact");

RegistrationBean registrationBean = new RegistrationBean();
registrationBean.setFirstName(firstName);
registrationBean.setLastName(lastName);
registrationBean.setUserName(userName);
registrationBean.setPassword(password);
registrationBean.setAddress(address);
registrationBean.setContact(contact);

RegistrationDao registrationDao = new RegistrationDao();

String userRegistered = registrationDao.registrationUser(registrationBean);
if(userRegistered.equals("SUCCESS"))   
{
request.getRequestDispatcher("/ProductSalesPage.jsp").forward(request, 
response);
}
else
{
request.setAttribute("errMessage", userRegistered);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/RegistrationServlet.jsp").forward(request, 
response);
}
}
}
```

RegistrationDao

```
package com.mvc.Dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mvc.Bean.RegistrationBean;
import com.mvc.RegistrationDB.RegistrationDB;

public class RegistrationDao {

public String registrationUser(RegistrationBean registrationBean)
{
String firstName = registrationBean.getFirstName();
String lastName = registrationBean.getLastName();
String userName = registrationBean.getUserName();
String password = registrationBean.getPassword();
String address = registrationBean.getAddress();
String contact = registrationBean.getContact();

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

try
{
con = RegistrationDB.createConnection();
String query = "insert into 
users(SlNo,firstName,lastName,userName,password,address,contact) values 
(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query); 
preparedStatement.setString(1, firstName);
preparedStatement.setString(2, lastName);
preparedStatement.setString(3, userName);
preparedStatement.setString(4, password);
preparedStatement.setString(5, address);
preparedStatement.setString(6, contact);

int i= preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

if (i!=0) 
return "SUCCESS"; 
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
return "Oops.. Something went wrong there..!";  
}
}
```

RegistrationDB

```
package com.mvc.RegistrationDB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class RegistrationDB {

public static Connection createConnection()
{
Connection con = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/project/users"; 
String username = "root"; 
String password = "password"; 
try 
{
try 
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); 
System.out.println("Printing connection object "+con);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
return con; 
}
}
```

RegistrationBean

```
package com.mvc.Bean;

public class RegistrationBean 

{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String address;
private String contact;

public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}
public String getAddress() {
return address;
}
public void setContact(String contact) {
this.contact = contact;
}
public String getContact() {
return contact;
}
}
```

Anything anyone can offer as far as why this servlet will not run would be gladly appreciated. The error messages that Eclipse throws are so generic, but the issue seems to be basically writing the registration information to the database. I can load the registration page and enter the information, and the if statements work because the page wont forward with blank text entry boxes or a password less than 6 characters. The problem is when you submit, and it throws HTTP Status 404 and says the requested resource is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're retrieving the incorrect parameter names in your RegistrationServlet.

For example: you are retrieving with `request.getParameter("firstname")` but your input have `name="firstName"`. Note the upper case 'N' (java EE servers are case sensitive for URIs).

Try this in your RegistrationServlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName"); // upper case N
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName"); // upper case N
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName"); // upper case N
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String contact = request.getParameter("contact");
    //...
```